# How to shift drawn text to top on UIView?

Tags: ios, text, uiview, core-graphics

I am drawing text on a UIView using core graphics, the restriction with this is that when the UIView is fully drawn to the end i can't shift all drawn text above to create empty line at the bottom to draw new text. I don't want to use the UITextView and UITableView.

**A visual explanation:**

Suppose a have a view as below to draw the text- 
[image]

So I am on the last line in this view and when this line is completely filled, I have to shift to one line below which is not there. What I want to do is to shift the whole screen text one line up (shifting out the first line from screen), to make space for new line.

This view is actually a larger one to provide scroll back, but to explain the situation I just mentioned so.

Is there any way to do so? Please suggest.

Comment: You are actually drawing the text onto the view. To shift it you have to redraw it. Or shift the view.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, @Revinder. Can you please post some code and/or an image that shows what is happening vs what you'd like to happen?

Comment: Why not use a `UITextView`?

Comment: it's terminal emulator, and textview can not fulfil the requirements, that why i want to use UIView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide scroll back, it means that you don't want to shift the whole text up to make space for one more line. Because in doing so you will lose the first line.

What you need to do is resize the view and make it bigger, this way you have more space to draw some more lines.

I would advise you to use a UITableView instead. It's too much work to draw the text by yourself and provide scrolling and all for no apparent advantage. Maybe just so you can learn how to do it :)

Comment: That's what I have used ultimately.